# mpich2mpi.dll was not found how to install mpich2mpi.dll on windows?

Tags: mpi, mpich

I am trying to run [OpenSeesMP](https://opensees.berkeley.edu/OpenSees/parallel/parallel.php) on Windows 10. I tried two different approaches 1) https://www.mpich.org/ and 2) [Microsoft MPI v10.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57467). However, I still get "mpich2mpi.dll was not found"

For some reason DLLs are not installed.

Please let me know if you have any clue!

Comment: Did you try googling the dll and downloading it

Comment: Yes I did. It seems to be part of MPICH2 from https://www.mpich.org/. They only offer source code for latest releases. I could find msi only for 1.4 version (https://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/1.4/) and that did not include dlls

Comment: Ymmv but there is this:https://www.pconlife.com/viewfileinfo/mpich2mpi-dll/